# Craft 3.1.7 live preview multi-site only works on home page

Tags: multi-site, live-preview

I am running sta-A and site-b on same installation.
I have cookie set for domain and have htaccess with CORS origin set to allow *, and also updated the nginx config to allow CORs. I know this last one works as font-awesome was blocked and is now working once i had updated the local nginx conf file.

The second domain only has live preview available on its home page. Any other entries created for the second domain have the link icon in the entries list in CP but when editing have no live preview option.

I thought 3.1.7 tokenized this?

Comment: Did you solve this in the end? I'm still having trouble with Live Preview and all SO answers just say it's fixed in 3.1+

Answer (score 1):

Are those the fields on the non-visible entries translatable by site? It's the most common problem, not setting up some of the fields or subfield as translatable by site.

Comment: No translation they both use same language. Two different domains.
The entry without preview button - its title has a translation symbol. Which is weird.

Comment: Are the sections enabled for both sites? If you go to the part of the section where the URI is defined, it should be active on the secondary site. 
What type of entries are they?

Comment: That doesn't make sense to enable because then admin can see site B entries in Site A entries view. Tried it to but still no preview on entries

Comment: The only other times I had that happening is when my section was not pointing to an existing template (for example changing a channel to single removes previous URI/template info but the entry still exists). It's kinda difficult to know without seeing the project.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I have an issue with live previews between sites, I have found it to be an issue with my security headers and/or `.htaccess` file.  Live preview uses an iframe, so if your site blocks iframes via security headers, then you obviously would not see its contents.

Check the console output via dev tools in your browser, and also check the logs under `storage/logs/` - it will tell you what is getting blocked and at which point.